# mvc application can't connect to database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

when I run my project from my local computer I can connect to the database just fine.  when I publish it I receive an error (below).  I believe the issue is with the app pool, but cant' figure out what it is.

this is a fresh install of everything, down to the OS

Identity - applicationpoolidentity

connection string

```
<add name="SPA_Impact_Reporting_TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/newRack.csdl|res://*/newRack.ssdl|res://*/newRack.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=serverip;initial catalog=dbname;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=T  rue;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

ERROR

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5872 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)

The network path was not found

```
Server Error in '/spadashboard' Application.
```

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +6600161
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6600667
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +99

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +10948975
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +136
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +91
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal(String commandText, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Object[] parameters) +109
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +87
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(String sql, Object[] parameters) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerable(String sql, Object[] parameters) +85
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(Type elementType, String sql, Object[] parameters) +260
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator() +34
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +28
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +220
   SPADash.Controllers.AccountsController.checkLogin(usrlogin cred) +151
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Comment: Error logs says necessary things. You should search first. -1 for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+40+%5Bmssql%5D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix error "Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841056/how-to-fix-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection)

Comment: I have researched this quesiton.  I wouldn't ask it if I didn't. The possible duplicate is wrong.  nothing there even remotely addresses my issue.  I have tried the tcp/ip  I have tried the named pipes.  I have tried adding a specific user for the application pool identity.  It connects perfectly fine from my development enviroment on my laptop.  only when published does it not work from either local host or remote computers.  What other information can be provided to help with an answer.

Comment: Super old question, but .. from the server your application is deployed to, `telnet <serverip> 1433`. Check firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try, change the applicaton pool identity from "AppPoolIdentity" to either "LocalSystem" or "NetworkService". See if this makes the issue go away

to change it go to run >> inetmgr and press enter

you should see your iis console .

on your left hand you can see application pool click on it by mouse and on your right hand on screen you can see set application pool default click on it it will pop up  anew window with many properties go for
identity and choose localsystem or network service and if you chose local service user account on machine  make sure you give the local service permission on your published folder

Comment: I have tried both of those accounts as well. no luck

Comment: Let .net do the pooling for you and open / close your connection with a using statement.

Suggestions:

Always open and close a connection like this, so .net can manage your connections and you won't run out of connections:

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
     conn.Open();
// do some stuff}
As I mentioned, check your query with sql server profiler and see if you can optimize it. Having a slow query with many requests in a web app can give these timeouts too.